# Replace multiple specific occurences with sed

Tags: awk, sed

I have large CSV file with current structure

```
380670000001,<n>,0,1970-01-01 00:00:00.00+0000,0,0,<n>,0,0
```

I have to replace  *"<n>"* in 2th and 4th columns to *"1970-01-01 00:00:00.00+0000"*
And replace *"<n>"* in others columns to *0*

Currently, I`m using an *awk* script:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{sub("<n>","1970-01-01 00:00:00.00+0000",$2); sub("<n>","1970-01-01 00:00:00.00+0000",$4);  gsub("<n>", 0); print}' input.txt > output.txt
```

Can this be done more elegant with *sed*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. In sed, there is no such thing as fields, so you would have to do a hard counting with regexes. It can be done, but not elegantly:

```
r='1970-01-01 00:00:00.00+0000'
sed -E "s/^([^,]*,)<n>/\1$r/;s/^(([^,]*,){3})<n>/\1$r/;s/<n>/0/g" file
```

(You may want to have a look at [Using \1 to keep part of the pattern](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-4) if you don't know back-references.)

Awk can be sanitized by setting shell variables, as I did above to sed, which are then passed to awk. So your awk script contains mostly only logic now:

```
r='1970-01-01 00:00:00.00+0000'
m='<n>'
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{sub(m,r,$2);sub(m,r,$4);gsub(m,"0")}1' r="$r" m="$m" file
```

A bit shorter:

```
awk -F, '{sub(m,r,$2);sub(m,r,$4);gsub(m,"0")}1' OFS=, r="$r" m="$m" file
```

Comment: Thanks, I will use AWK for this case, because it is much faster(almost 2X), but it is good to know, that this task can be solved with sed!

Answer (score 1):

No, it can't be done more elegantly with sed, but here's a bit more elegant way to do it in awk:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS=","; n="<n>"; r="1970-01-01 00:00:00.00+0000" }
    { for (i=2;i<=4;i+=2) if ($i == n) $i=r; gsub(n,0) }
1' file
380670000001,1970-01-01 00:00:00.00+0000,0,1970-01-01 00:00:00.00+0000,0,0,0,0,0
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below awk command

```
echo "380670000001,<n>,0,1970-01-01 00:00:00.00+0000,0,0,<n>,0,0"| awk -F "," '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(i ~ /2|4/){gsub("<n>","1970-01-01 00:00:00.00+0000",$i)}else{gsub("<n>","0") }}}1'
```

output

```
380670000001,0,0,1970-01-01 00:00:00.00+0000,0,0,0,0,0
```

Comment: `i ~ /2|4/` would be true for fields 12, 23, 45, etc. You need to anchor it. The first arg for all `sub()` functions is a regexp, not a string so you should be using regexp (`/<n>/`) instead of string (`"<n>"`) delimiters. `gsub()` is for doing multiple substitutions on a string, you're only doing 1 replacement of the whole string so you should be using `sub()` instead.